# Spark Streaming: microbatches getting queued

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

Was trying to do a sample window Function using pyspark.

```
conf = (SparkConf()
     .setMaster("local[2]")
     .setAppName("PythonStreamingKafka")
     )

sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)
input_stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [thing_topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})

messages = input_stream.map(lambda x: x[1]).window(10,5)
messages.foreachRDD(windowMetrics)

def windowMetrics(rdd):
     print ("Window RDD size:", rdd.count())
```

Receiving data from Kafka. Once execution started,as you can see in the below Spark GUI only one batch is executed and all other batches goes to queue. Actually no processing is happening inside the window because kafka not any supplying data for processing (InputSize =0).

[image: SaprkGUI]

If window operations are not used it works perfectly fine. Code below.

```
 messages = input_stream.map(lambda x: x[1])
 messages.foreachRDD(windowMetrics)
```

Tried some googling and found some related content and none of them having the same issue.

[Spark Streaming: long queued/active batches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252198/spark-streaming-long-queued-active-batches)

Here in-between batches are getting queued.

https://forums.databricks.com/questions/1276/kafka-direct-api-from-spark-streaming-what-happens.html

Here discussed about back-pressure. Since there is no supplied data, hope there will not be any back-pressure.